# winning strategy algorithm for simple game [2 players moving on grid field]

Tags: algorithm

I'm searching for a winning algorithm in this game:
-game is played on grid (we can say its infinite grid)
-there are two players, 1 (orange) starts and his move is long exactly 1, player 2 (green) is second and his move is long exactly 2, they take turns
-goal for the second player is, to get to the start (he wins even if the player 1 gets there)
-goal for the first player is to never get to starting point or to somehow block the game so there are no more moves
-they cannot go through path (points) where they had already been

here are some examples of the game (in game 3 orange player wins, because there are no more moves)
[image]

I would be grateful for any help on this (links if this is known solved algorithm, or pseudo-code, or just plain simple text from which could be the strategy understood)
thanks
m,

Comment: if you are the orange, your winning strategy is to get to a cell that has an odd distance from goal simply 0, 1 or 3, you need to avoid distance=2 since that'd make checkmate

Comment: How did you come across this game? A bit of context might help.

Comment: @PengOne I chose to programm this 'game' as a school project and one of the mode should be with using this algorithm, so the player always loose to computer

Comment: @KhaledAKhunaifer I'm not sure about this, since in example 2 on the picture u got to dostance 1 from origin and still lose, since your only move is to the origin (which means lost for orange player)

Comment: Why is game 3 a win for orange? Can't green just move to the starting point and win?

Comment: @Dukeling No, his move is long exatly 2, cannot go 1

Comment: Oh, missed that part.

Comment: @m4tu5 Then, you have 2 keys, staying away from the origin point, and staying away from a dead-end .. to stay away from a dead-end, you stay away from moving into a position can let the green move into a dead-end, which is a closed-corner with generally an odd linear path, since if orange is to complete each consecutive move, that'd be multiple of 3, otherwise its distance on the form 3K+2 orange will win

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Since orange player moves only one, move in the direction away from direction of start point. 1. Initially move top(Suggestion), 
   Green can end up on 7 possible points after its move. Check direction of start from present       point.
2. If it is bottom left from start point, move orange either further down or further left. this way you never make a move towards the start point.

To improve this further you can store all moves played till then on a database and decide whether to move down or left(In step 2) based on the following:

> if there are more number of moves to the left of the current position, compared to those to the bottom of the current position ----> move down else move left.

PS: The initial move can be anything. The strategy is to move away and avoid getting stuck between moves.

Answer (score 0):

Orange can always win by always moving further away from the origin. Based on nonintersecting random walks in the plane, this strategy is robust against anything green might try.

---

If you want to do the analysis right, here's how to get started.

With most game theory problems, the key is to work backwards from the end. Let's be green first, and let's assume that we have the last move. For now, to keep things simple, let's ignore the "avoid prior paths" condition. We can add that back in once we understand the simpler version.

Let's digress for a moment to say that "distance" must be hamming distance in our simplified version. Once we account for obstructions, by the "distance between two points" we mean the length of the shortest path *that does not intersect an existing game path* between the given points. If no such path exists, say the distance is infinite.

In the simple version, each of green's moves changes the distance to the origin by 0 or 2, and each of orange's moves changes the distance to the origin by 1. Keeping this in mind, we work from the end...

If we hit the origin, we win, so we will win if orange puts us distance 2 from the origin. Since orange moves one step per move, we win if we land distance 1 from the origin (since orange must either move to distance 0 or to distance 2). If we land distance 3 from the origin, then we win if orange moves to distance 2, but not necessarily if he moves to distance 4. In this case, we can quickly see that orange can always keep moving away from the origin (as in a nonintersecting random walk) and we never return. However, we still have useful information that two factors are key:

1. Parity is important. Green wants to start from an even distance to win.
2. Green must wind the path around to stop orange from running away.

Comment: If Orange sticks to the simple strategy of moving away from the origin, he loses. To counteract, Green needs to always make L-shaped moves that bring him closer to the origin. The game ends in 8 half-moves.

Comment: @n.m. No, if Orange always moves away then Green cannot counter this and they end up far, far away until someone (presumably Green) gives up.

Comment: @PengOne but orange move by 1 block and green by two, he can always 'dictate' the direction.. at elast i think
i dont really understand how orange can always win this

Comment: orange:right green:up,left o:u g:l,d o:l g:d,r o:d g:r,u x. Counter that.

Comment: I also think that there is strategy for green, not orange :X